# Upgrading Tensorflow to 1.3.0 and cuDNN

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, cudnn

I upgraded my TensorFlow 1.0.1 with

```
$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

on Ubuntu 16.04, cuDNN 5.1.5 and CUDA 8.0

However, there's error message when I import tensorflow in python module as below:

```
>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24,                                            in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I think this is the problem with cuDNN version compatibility. 
Anyone knows how to upgrade cuDNN and make compatible with tensorflow 1.3.0??

Comment: tensorflow==1.3.0 doesn't support `cudnn=5.1` it needs `cudnn=6`

Comment: I think so. But I wanna know how upgrade cuDNN. I wonder just installing the cuDNN 6 is sufficient.. doesn't need to 'configure' step?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow 1.3 requires cuDNN version 6. Follow the installation instructions for your platform on [NVIDIA's cuDNN website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn). Once cuDNN 6 is installed successfully, your installation of TensorFlow 1.3 should start working.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script which can be used to upgrade the cuDNN version with a clean install. You can download the script from:

https://github.com/dnzzcn/cuDNNv

This is what the script does:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f /usr/include/cudnn.h
rm -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*libcudnn*
rm -f /usr/local/cuda-*/lib64/*libcudnn*


cp -P packages/cudnn/include/cudnn.h /usr/include
cp -P packages/cudnn/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
chmod a+r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn*

rm -rf packages/cudnn
```

It performs the installation operations automatically for the version you need.

If you have TensorFlow 1.3.0, which requires cuDNN v6.0, installing cuDNN v6.0 by using the script will be sufficient.